# Passing time from DateTimePicker to database parameters

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-4.0

I have form with `DateTimePicker` and it is format `Time` and I want to pass time from DateTimePicker to database parameters as shown below but I am getting error message that says at line of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

> {"Procedure or function 'PROC_REGISTER_SESSION' expects parameter '@START_TIME', which was not supplied."}

I set breakpoint and checked all parameters and they are filled with data 
also test message box are filled with data

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartTime", SqlDbType.Time)).Value = DTP_StartTime.Value.TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: Everything is in the error `function expects parameter '@START_TIME'`. Where is your `@START_TIME` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explaining:

> {"Procedure or function 'PROC_REGISTER_SESSION' expects parameter
>   '@START_TIME', which was not supplied."}

You pass a parameter as `@StartTime` not `@START_TIME`.

So this should fix (at least one) error:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@START_TIME", SqlDbType.Time)).Value = DTP_StartTime.Value.TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: I expected OP will find this by himself :( But the answer is correct, can't argue with that :)

Comment: sorry what a shame stupid mistake ... long working hours  thanks problem solved